# How to define a variable which can be modified and accessed across classes

Tags: python

## Modifyin Question by adding details

I have one class in `general.py`:

```
class TestProcedure:
    name = "Undefined test procedure"
    description = None
    sequence_count = 0
    .....
```

Keeping the above class as base, I create various classes in various files for e.g.
One of the files is `file1.py`:

```
from general import *

class F1(TestProcedure):

    def performTest(self):
        #HERE I WANT TO INCREMENT sequence_count#
```

Second file is `file2.py`:

```
from general import *   

class F2(TestProcedure):

    def performTest(self):
        #HERE WHEN I TRY TO ACCESS sequence_count I GET A LAST MODIFIED VALUE#
```

As shown above i have need several such classes which will try to access sequence_Count and whenever i try to execute any of the files `sequence_count` gets last modified value.

If there is any way to do the same then please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you are updating `sequence_count` but if you were to update the attribute on the original **class** and not the *instance* then it should be reflected to all inherited classes.

e.g.

```
class TestProcedure(object):
    sequence_count = 0

class F1(TestProcedure):
    pass

# These are instances of your class
# We will modify one later to see what happens
class_instance = F1()
un_altered_class_instance = F1()

# This is updating your class
TestProcedure.sequence_count = 20

# This is updating the instance of your class
class_instance.sequence_count = 5

new_class_instance = F1()

print(F1.sequence_count)
# 20
print(class_instance.sequence_count)
# 5
# This outputs 5 as we modified the attribute of the instance
print(un_altered_class_instance.sequence_count)
# 20
# This outputs 20 as we did not modify the attribute of this instance 
print(new_class_instance.sequence_count)
# 20
```

As you can see from the example above this will update your original class and anything inheriting from it including instances that have not already had the `sequence_count` attribute modified. If they have, as seen from above in `class_instance`, they will keep their modified value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a global variable (well, within the module anyway).  Almost certainly there is some better design alternative which avoids the coupling you seek here, but without more details, a global variable seems to be the simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

All the variables define inside a class definition are static by default. And hence what you can do is use TestProcedure.sequence_count in place of sequence_count everywhere and the changes will be reflected in all the files.